# TinyMCE warning: Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, tinymce

We're using [Website Publisher](https://www.interspire.com/websitepublisher/) version 5.1.7 on one of our website and we're getting TinyMCE warning

> Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead (606 out of range 134)

in FireFox and Chrome latest versions. Previously, TinyMCE was working perfectly without any warnings and after we'd upgrade to latest browser version, then we start getting the warning in FireBug. Because of this warning the data doesn't loads in the TinyMCE. See the attached screenshot.

Since, the support for Website Publisher has been discontinued, so we're finding no luck to resolve that issue. We also have a google re-search but nothing is working in our way. We've tried to use the new TinyMCE Compressor version but it is not working either.

Does anyone experienced the same warning for TinyMCE in FireFox and Chrome browsers?

Can anybody here help us out with this warning?

NOTE: We're using TinyMCE PHP Compressor version 3.x.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can anybody help us out with the issue related to TinyMCE?

Comment: Have you been able to solve it? I am facing same issue

Comment: No, we're still unable to solve that issue from Website Publisher. But, we've provided our client an alternate solution since we were running out of time and our client was anxious to modify his homepage content. We gave him a separate area to modify the homepage content.

If you find any solution do post here that would be really good for everyone since nobody yet solved that issue with Website Publisher.

Thanks.

Comment: I had started bounty on it. I am also running out of time for my client. I am going to switch to other available html-editors.

Answer (score 0):

DOM MutationObserver – reacting to DOM changes without killing browser performance.
in September 2011 a group of Google and Mozilla engineers announced a new proposal that would offer similar functionality with improved performance: DOM MutationObserver. This new DOM Api is available in Firefox and Webkit nightly builds, as well as Chrome 18.

you can find more information here [DOM MutationObserver](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)

Comment: Yes, correct. It seems like this is the problem, since many of the other Jquery features aren't working as well on web publisher. 

What would be the solution since we don't want to specify each and every element ID to observe for change?

What would be the global solution for that. Please suggest?

Comment: What would be the solution? I could not find one so I switched to CKeditor?